# delete all values and left with one

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a table like:

```
uid | name | user_id
--------------------
1   | aaa  | 111 
2   | bbb  | 111
3   | ccc  | 222
4   | aaa  | 222
5   | vvv  | 333
6   | zzz  | 333
7   | aaa  | 111
8   | bbb  | 111
```

I want to write a query like it will delete all the name `aaa` but left one time `aaa`.

output like this:

```
  uid | name | user_id
  --------------------
    1 | aaa  | 111
    2 | bbb  | 111
    3 | ccc  | 222
    4 | aaa  | 222
    5 | vvv  | 333
    6 | zzz  | 333
```

Is it possible by query.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE  a
FROM    table tbl
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  user_id, MIN(uid) min_uid, name
            FROM    table
            GROUP   BY user_id, name
        ) tbl1 ON  tbl.user_id = tbl1.user_id AND
                tbl.uid = tbl1.min_uid AND
                tbl.name = tbl1.name
WHERE   tbl1.user_id IS NULL
```

you have to compare name and uid both to delete all duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

try something like that it will work
if you want to keep the row with the lowest id value

```
DELETE n1 FROM tablename n1, tablename n2 WHERE n1.uid > n2.uid AND n1.name = n2.name
```

if you want to keep the row with the highest id value.

```
DELETE n1 FROM tablename n1, tablename n2 WHERE n1.uid < n2.uid AND n1.name = n2.name
```

Comment: I'm assuming `name` is the assumed table name?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though you need to be careful with this one.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE `name`;
```

(Check the documentation for the exact syntax if this doesn't work)

This will make the 'name' column unique and mercilessly drop all duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT` also.

```
select distinct name from my_table
```

Comment: This won't alter the table contents though.

Comment: No, but its possible to redirect the output to a new table.